# Публичный API, ограничение доступа по домену без авторизации

Tags: php, ajax, api

Пишу API для своего сервиса. Клиентам на их сайты будет устанавливаться JS-скрипт, который по AJAX будет передавать параметры в api и получать набор данных, актуальных для клиента. Авторизации не будет никакой, потому как доступ к этим данным должны иметь все гостевые посетители сайта-клиента.

Но хотелось бы ограничить выдачу данных только если ajax-запрос пришел с доверенного домена. Была бы авторизация, всё понятно - авторизовался, получил токен. Есть токен - есть данные. Нет токена - до свидания. Тогда если правильный токен скомпроментирован - проблемы владельца сайта-клиента.

Можно ли вообще решить подобную проблему и куда копать, не могу понять с какой стороны подступиться.

Comment: Из браузеров — referer и access-control-allow-origin, из всего остального — никак

Comment: мне казалось что referer подменить проще простого

Comment: В браузере подменить нельзя, а во всём остальном подменить возможно что угодно

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте таблицу `allowed_ip`. В ней, запишите всех доступных клиентов.
Пишите данные в кеш, и при создании/удалении/обновлении записей в таблице - перезаписывайте.

Когда у Вас приходит запрос, проверяйте по IP-адресу в кеше.
Затем, отправлять JSON:

`{ 'status' : 0, 'data': [], 'message' : 'Error' }` при ошибке

`{ 'status' : 1, 'data': [], 'message' : ' Success' }` при успехе

Есть еще один вариант, отправлять дополнительно приватный токен, проверяя IP и доменное имя.

Comment: Интересовало, каким именно методом проверять валидность домена. Именно домена, думаю, а не ip. Потому как shared хостинги никто не отменял.

Comment: Предыдущий комментатор сказал через Referer. Я честно говоря думал его легко подменить, оказалось все чуть сложнее. Наверное подойдет.

Comment: @toxxxa, реферрер можно подменить. Но можно сохранять domain_name + ip